# How to run consumer @StreamListener only after ApplicationReadyEvent method completed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, kafka-consumer-api, event-listener

I have a consumer method with

```
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
method()
```

And I have a method with an event listener

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
method()...
```

Is it possible to configure @StreamListener to start listening only after @EventListener method is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Spring Cloud Stream [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties) you could use property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<bindingName>.consumer.autoStartup=false` which will stop `BindingService` from automatically starting consumer binding. Then you can do it yourself whenever you need, e.g. in `ApplicationReadyEvent` listener.

```
public class DelayedBindingStarter {

    private final BindingsEndpoint bindingsEndpoint;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void applicationReady() {
        bindingsEndpoint.changeState("binding_name", BindingsLifecycleController.State.STARTED);
    }
}
```